# Kotlin ArrayList overlapping value plus?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, arraylist, overlapping

I'm using ArrayList.

I'd like to get the sum of these.

ex ) Apple = 9,300, Banana = 5,400

But these are added fluidly.

I don't know what to do.

```
class Statement_data(var name : String, var Value : Int) {

}
```

name    value
Apple   3,000
Apple   3,100
Banana  2,000
orange  1,500
Apple   3,200
berry   3,500
Banana  3,400
orange  1,600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter by the name, and then use `sumBy` on the value. Using `asSequence()` is optional, but it allows it to skip copying the list contents when you filter it.

```
val numApples = list.asSequence().filter { it.name == "Apple" }.sumBy(Statement_data::Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `groupBy` operator: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html

```
val list = listOf(
    Statement_data("Apple",9300),
    ...
)
val map = list.groupBy { it.name}
```

This will return a Map<String, List>. Then you can use the `sumBy` operator, in your case:

```
val applesCount = map["Apple"].sumBy{ it.Value }
```

See documentation for more details:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html